# how to select an iframe tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I m trying to give style to an iframe but it not work

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").style.resize ="vertical";
```

I have to give this style to this iframe tag. But when i try this code it gives me error like:

```
property 'resize' of undefined
    at editPart (c2fd0a58-2ee5-4f88-a11d-c99edf724bbe:443)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick (c2fd0a58-2ee5-4f88-a11d-c99edf724bbe:1)
```

this is javascript part:

```
function editPart(url) {

$("#windowEditPart").kendoWindow({
    content: {
        url: url
    }
});
var kendoWindowData = $('#windowEditPart').data('kendoWindow');
kendoWindowData.refresh();
kendoWindowData.center().open();

    window.createTimeout(() => {
         document.getElementsByClassName("k-content")[1].style.resize = "vertical";
    }, 0);
}
```

here s html part of iframe

```
<iframe title="Editable area. Press F10 for toolbar." frameborder="0" class="k-content" src='javascript:""'>

</iframe>
```

Comment: The problem isn't within setting resize to vertical, it's about document.getElementsByTageName failing to capture an element. Please share your HTML, so we can debug this problem.

Comment: Are you using Kendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, so you have to select the first item in the returned array:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.resize = "vertical";
```

If you know the class you could use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("k-content")[i].style.resize = "vertical";
```

where is the index of your iframe in the list of all elements with the class `k-content`